# Variable std_logic_vector or array entry in vhdl

Tags: aes, vhdl

I'm currently working on AES encryption using keys of three different sizes (128,192, and 256 bit).

I was wondering if I can declare / use a `std_logic_vector` of a variable size? For example, can I just have one input port and I get to know wether it's 128,192, or 256 bit based on the user input?

Or else if I choose the max key length, which is 256 bit, can I assign a 128 or 192 bit key to that `std_logic_vector`? Or will an error message appear?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. A variable is a class of object in VHDL as is a signal. If you mean supplying an expression to an assignment target that can't be implicitly subtype converted (e.g. the lengths don't match) that will produce an error. AES lends itself to key loading ports of 32 or 64, longer can derail synthesis. You can conditionally assign slices of the target or length stuff  in any event for pure behavioral models. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update and 10.6.2 Simple variable assignments for the subtype conversion requirements.

Comment: My question is simply instead of defining 3 input keys ( i.e key_128 : in : std_logic_vector(127 downto 0) and another two for 192 and 256 keys. Can I just make one input and I get to know wether it's 128,192,256 based on the user input

Comment: Must the length be variable at run-time or only at compilation  (elaboration) time? Do you target synthesis or only simulation?

Comment: You can certainly make an input port's size dependent on a generic. It will be fixed when you elaborate the design.

Comment: @MartinZabel my target is simulation

Comment: @BrianDrummond can you elaborate please with an example

Answer (score 0):

If the size of key changes at run-time, you will have to declare
the corresponding objects (signals, constants, variables) with the
maximum possible size. The actual key length will then be defined by another
signal or variable. The maximum size may be defined as below.

If you declare an object of type `std_logic_vector` with the maximum possible size, then assigning a shorter `std_logic_vector` will result in an error. You will have to extend the right-hand aside of the assignment to the size of the target object first, e.g. using the following `resize` function from the [PoC Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) where I'm one of the authors:

```
function resize(vec : std_logic_vector; length : natural; fill : std_logic := '0') return std_logic_vector is
constant  high2b : natural := vec'low+length-1;
    constant  highcp : natural := imin(vec'high, high2b);
variable  res_up : std_logic_vector(vec'low to high2b);
variable  res_dn : std_logic_vector(high2b downto vec'low);
begin
if vec'ascending then
  res_up := (others => fill);
  res_up(vec'low to highcp) := vec(vec'low to highcp);
  return  res_up;
else
  res_dn := (others => fill);
  res_dn(highcp downto vec'low) := vec(highcp downto vec'low);
  return  res_dn;
    end if;
end function;
```

For example, given a 128-bit `std_logic_vector` named `source`, this can be re-sized to 256 bit with:

```
resize(source, 256) -- returns a 256-bit std_logic_vector
```

The function works like the `resize` function on `unsigned` and `signed` from package `numeric_std`.

---

If the key size is known at compile (elaboraton) time, then you will
have two options. A usual approach is to define the key size by a
constant and passing the key size via generics to sub-components.
The following entity `test` has a generic `SIZE` specifying the key
size. The length of ports as well as other objects, can now be defined
depending on this generic.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is
  generic (
    SIZE : positive := 128); -- the default value can be omitted
  port (
    x : in  std_logic_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0);
    y : out std_logic_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0));
end entity test;

architecture rtl of test is
begin  -- architecture rtl
  y <= not x;
end architecture rtl;
```

The generic can now be bound during the instantiation of this entity,
for example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test_tb is
end entity test_tb;

architecture rtl of test_tb is
  constant SIZE : positive := 192;
  signal x : std_logic_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal y : std_logic_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0);
begin  -- architecture rtl

  dut: entity work.test
    generic map (
      SIZE => SIZE)
    port map (
      x => x,
      y => y);

end architecture rtl;
```

Of course, the length of the actuals (right side in port map) must
match the length of the formals (left side in port map). This approach
is supported by all (major) VHDL synthesis tools. If default values
for the generics are present, then `test` can be directly synthesized as
top-level module.

---

The second option, for a fixed key-size during elaboration, would be
to use unconstrained arrays (`std_logic_vector`) in the port
declaration of the entity. The actual size of the array can be
determined with the `length` atribute, and the actual range with the
`range` attribute, for example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test2 is
  port (
    x : in  std_logic_vector;
    y : out std_logic_vector);
end entity test2;

architecture rtl of test2 is
  signal z : std_logic_vector(x'range);
begin  -- architecture rtl
  z <= x;
  y <= not z;

  assert false report "x'length=" & integer'image(x'length) severity note;
end architecture rtl;
```

The range (and length) of the port signals will then be
constrained by the associated actual in the component instantiation.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test2_tb is
end entity test2_tb;

architecture rtl of test2_tb is
  constant SIZE : positive := 192;
  signal x : std_logic_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal y : std_logic_vector(SIZE-1 downto 0);
begin  -- architecture rtl

  dut: entity work.test2
    port map (
      x => x,
      y => y);

end architecture rtl;
```

This works in simulation. But, I'm not sure whether it is supported by
the (major) VHDL synthesis tools. Of course, for synthesis of `test2`
another top-level entity is required which instantiates `test2` to
constraint the array ranges.